# UIWebView is asking for location permission

Tags: ios, uiwebview, location

I am developing an application that shows a mobile web site in UIWebView. This web site uses location. Even tough i have granted permision for location to the app. UIWebView asking for location permission (in English) every time i open the app.

App requesting location acces:

[image: Give location acces to the app]

UIWebView requesting location acces:

[image: Give location acces to the UIWebView]

Can I make UIWebView stop asking for location permission or make the app ask for location when UIWebview loads the web site but only once?

**UPDATE:**

I have solved the English problem by localizing the Info.plist strings.

Comment: Me too facing same problem. Any solution found ?

Answer (score -1):

Since your application has permission to get the user's location, can't it just pass that information on to your website as part of the initial URL (in the query string)?

So, It is asking for accessing location permission to your webview. Though if you open that url everytime, It will ask for location permission if it failed to found access enable.